# Permanently Export PYTHONPATH OSX

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7

I've set this at the end of my .bash_profile:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
```

But it seems it's not working, because when I start the Terminal it does not recognise the modules, but if I do it directly on the Terminal it works ok, but only for that session. When I start the Terminal again, it does not work.

I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Do you see the path when you `echo $PYTHONPATH` in a new terminal window?

Comment: is the `.bash_profile` file in the correct user folder, and is the terminal & python process in it being run as the corresponding user as well?

Comment: Try double (`"`) quotes!

Comment: @plg No, they are not necessary or useful here.

Comment: Huh, I always thought they were otherwise spaces were expanded as in most expressions. Good to know

Comment: @garnertb I see the path, but only after I export it manually in the terminal

Comment: @GP89 yep, everything is in the right path and folders

Comment: Does changing your cwd have an effect?

Answer (score 1):

`.bash_profile` files only get sourced by login shells. You need to logout and login again for the changes to take effect. Alternatively, use `.bashrc`. This gets sourced everytime a new shell opens.

It's worrying that you need to add site packages to your path. Are you sure python installed correctly? What are the values of `sys.prefix` and `sys.exec_prefix`? Python searches for site packages under these directories. See the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) for more details.

Comment: Yes, I was wondering that to! I don't know why my packages aren't being recognised. The value of sys.prefix is '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7' and sys.exec_prefix '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'

Comment: Python looks for site packages under those directories. For instance, `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/site-python`.

Comment: I'm using lpthw.web (same as web.py), and when I run the script it says 'ImportError: No module named web'